# Copy data from one sheet to another sheet (in another file in different folder)

Tags: directory, copy, spreadsheet, paste

I want to copy the data (e.g. range A1: F15) from 'sheet1' of currrent sheet into 'sheet2' of file ABC (e.g. range C3: H17) which is located in a sub-folder 'sub-folder'.

I know how to copy from one to another sheet within the same file but I I don't kwow how to do with different file.

Please help.

```
function SendToSubT() {
  var Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var record = Sheet1.getSheetValues(1,1,6,15);
  var folder_root = DriveApp.getFolderById(Folder ID of my root folder);
  var folder_Sub1 = DriveApp.getFolderById(Folder ID of sub-folder);
  var parentFolder = folder_Sub1.getParents();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().SpreadsheetByName('ABC');
  ss.getRange(3,3,6,15).setValues(record);
}
```